# Why we don't need dataType: "json" in AJAX call (conditionally)?

Tags: php, json

I noticed that we don't need to include `dataType: "json"` in our AJAX call if the server file is already in `.json` format, e.g.

**index.html**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/test.json",
    data: "id="+id,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response){
        // Some more stuff here...
    }
});
```

**test.json**

```
{ 
    "fname" : "Aileen", 
    "lname" : "Brown", 
    "email" : "ab@gmail.com", 
    "phone" : "1234567890", 
    "country" : "USA" 
}
```

But if we have to fetch above content from a PHP file through MySQL database

**index.html**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/test.php",
    data: "id="+id,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        // Some more stuff here...
    }
});
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
$data = array(
                "fname"     => "Aileen",
                "lname"     => "Brown",
                "email"     => "ab@gmail.com",
                "phone"     => "1234567890",
                "country"   => "USA"
            );

// Convert PHP array into JSON object
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The response from this server PHP file via AJAX call in web browser console is collected in the same JSON format as my `test.json` file has.

```
{"fname":"Aileen","lname":"Brown","email":"ab@gmail.comk","phone":"1234567890","country":"USA"}
```

Can anyone please explain me properly why using `dataType: "json"` is mandatory when the data has to be fetched from a PHP file rather than a JSON file if the format of data coming from server is identical?

Comment: According to the doc ( https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ) , if you don't specify the datatype, it will try to infer it based on the MIME type in the response header. So perhaps when you retrieve the results from a JSON file, that MIME type is already set by the server that sends it. So if your PHP code set the appropriate MIME header before outputting the data, you wouldn't need to tell your JS code what to expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, this is because of a bug in your PHP code.

Any HTTP request or response with a body has a matching `Content-Type` in the headers to describe what type of data it is.

By default, jQuery will parse the response it gets according to the `Content-Type` header it came with. `dataType` causes it to ignore that header (and also set an `Accept` header on the request).

Most web servers these days are configured *by default* so that a file with a `.json` file extension gets a `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Any PHP program will output, again *by default*, a `Content-Type: text/html` header unless overridden using the [`header` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Since your PHP doesn't include `header("Content-Type: application/json")` it tells the web browser that it is sending HTML and jQuery tries to parse the JSON as if it were HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Content-Type` sent in the header for a `.json` file is already `application/json` whereas a "normal" PHP file has `text/html`.

jQuery AJAX uses "Intelligent Guess" to determine the data type from the MIME type of the file if no `dataType` is set:

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

*(see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)*

You can easily watch this behavior in your Developer Console (here I used Firefox's built-in version):

[image: Example]